# Populate a javascript array with links of a specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking to take a website source and populate an array with a collection of links, filtered by their `a class`.

Say, for instance, the links were `<a class="title">`, how could I target each class and add the URL to an array?

Would Javascript or jQuery work better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var arr = new Array();
$("a.title").each(function()
{
    arr.push($(this).attr("href"));
});
```

So, basically you create an array by using the [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) constructor. Then you use JQuery's [each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method to iterate over the links with class `title`, getting their urls using the [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method and pushing them in the array along the way.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy with jQuery:

```
var arr = [];
var ptr = 0;

$('.title').each(function() {
    arr[ptr] = $(this).attr('href');
    ptr++;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
var collectionOfLinks = {};
$('a').each(function() {
    var cl = $(this).attr('class');
    if (collectionOfLinks[cl] === undefined) {
        collectionOfLinks[cl] = [];
        collectionOfLinks[cl].push($(this).attr('href'));
    }else{
        collectionOfLinks[cl].push($(this).attr('href'));
    }
});
```

With this you end up with an object whose properties names are the classes of the `<a>` elements and whose values are arrays of href

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery, you can do `var urls = $("a.title").attr("href")`to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below,

```
var linkURL = [];
$('a.title').each (function () {
   linkURL.push(this.href);
});
```